# Element implicitly has 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: typescript

I want to have an object that's indexed by an id of type string and has a value of a string.

Here's my interface:

```
interface Bars {
  [id: string]: string;
}
```

the `bars` objects seen below is an array of objects where the keys are a string (`barId`) and string value (`myVal`) in the reducer.

```
const bars = barsResponse.bar.reduce((acc, bar) => {
    acc[bar.barId as string] = bar.myVal;
    return acc;
  }, {});
```

What am I doing wrong here that TypeScript is shouting:

`Element implicitly has 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'`

Comment: `Bars` is a type. What does `typeof Bars` mean? If it's supposed to bey `keyof Bars`, based on the description of your objects, I see no problem. Could you setup a MCVE?

Comment: well the type of `bar.barId` should be string, but when I try `acc[bar.barId as string]` it's still the same error. so my attempt at `as typeof Bars` above is wildly incorrect and I'm not entirely sure how to fix the problem, hence why I'm here.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Can you set up a MCVE, in the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), for instance?

Comment: Please provide a self-contained plaintext [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE.  Right now there are undeclared things, and that means I can't start working on the solution before first working on re-creating the problem.  If you decide to do this and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to assign a type to the accumulator parameter or the default return value

```js
reduce((acc:Bars, bar) => {...}

const bars = bar.reduce((acc, bar) => {
  acc[bar.barId as string] = bar.myVal;
  return acc;
}, {} as Bars);
```

Comment: Alternatively, TS supports using a type argument for reduce: `bar.reduce<Bars>(..., {})`, no `as` needed.